# One of the subviews of a stack view not showing up at all

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I want my stack view to have three views: red image, blue image and register view. The thing is that while the red and blue button appear just fine, the register view does not.

[image]

This is how I set up and place my stack view inside my view controller view:

```
func setupSocialStackView() {
    let socialStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: redImage, blueImage, registerView])
    socialStackView.axis = .vertical
    socialStackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
    view.addSubview(socialStackView)
    socialStackView.spacing = 8

    // NSLayoutAnchor constraints here to place stack view 
    // inside my view controller view
}
```

This is the code for my register view which doesn't show up:

```
lazy var registerView: UIView = {
    let containerView = UIView()

    // Register button
    let registerButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    registerButton.setTitle("Register", for: .normal)
    registerButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: UIFontWeightLight)
    registerButton.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    registerButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    registerButton.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor(r: 91, g: 90, b: 90)
    registerButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(presentRegisterController), for: .touchUpInside)
    containerView.addSubview(registerButton)

    return containerView
}()
```

The other two arrange views of the stack view are `UIImageView`s.

Why are the two images there and the register view is not? Am I missing something?

Comment: can you show the constraints of the view not being displayed?

Comment: A `UIView` by default has no `intrinsicContentSize` so to use it with a `UIStackView` with a vertical axis you need to add a height constraints. As it is the stack view is setting your register view's height to 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't appear to be giving your UIButton a frame size. See what you get if you add an autoresizingMask line:

```
    registerButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(presentRegisterController), for: .touchUpInside)

    registerButton.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    containerView.addSubview(registerButton)
```

Answer (score 3):

For me, I needed to add bottom, right, and left constraints for the view inside the stack view. Then it appeared.

Answer (score 2):

The view that isn't showing up is the container `UIView`, which has no intrinsic size. Inside your `lazy var` block, constrain the edges of the `registerButton` to the `containerView`, so that the container view has a size.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are making a subclass of a UIView in order to show a button saying "Register?". That is way too complicated, a UIButton is already subclass of UIView, so all you need to do is add the register button directly to your stackview! Hope that helps

Comment: I've actually wanted to add more stuff to the register view, not just a button. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Ok, why do you have a container UIView inside your register UIView? Simply add the register button to self.addSubview. Also as @beyowulf said, if you add a UIView to a stack, it does not know how big it should be, so you need to either give the view a height constraint, or you can constraint your register button to the register view (using autolayout, not frames), so that you register view knows how big its content will be.

Answer (score -1):

First add all 3views in a **stackview**. Set its **Spacing** and **distribution**  from the attribute inspector from the right side.eg(spacing=10, distribution=fill equality).Now select the stack view and add the respective constraints.

You can try this.